# Justifying a product of matrices have the rows i and j if the matrix A has the rows i and j equal with i different than j

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A \in M_{m \times n}$ and $B \in M_{n \times p}$. Justify that: If $A$ has the rows $i$ and $j$ equal with $i \neq j$ the matrix $AB$ has the rows $i$ and $j$ equal.

I don't know how to justify this condition, as, honestly, don't even understand it. Can you, please, explain it and maybe give an example?

Comment: Please do not $\LaTeX$ text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $i$-th row of $AB$ is $$\sum_{l=1}^nA_{il}\cdot B_{l*}.$$ Here $B_{l*}$ denotes the $l$-th row of $B$. Similiary, $j$-th row of $AB$ is $$\sum_{l=1}^nA_{jl}\cdot B_{l*}.$$ Now, $A_{i*}=A_{j*}\implies A_{il}=A_{jl}$ for all $l=1,...,n$. So we are done.

Comment: I think my confusion was that they said i equal to j and then i different to j. They probably meant that i and j rows have the same elements, hence being equal, but that they're talking about different rows, thus saying they're different. If they used a different notation for i and j, would probably not have been as confusing. Thanks for clarifying!